# Youtube debug info field details

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I am just doing a r&d on youtube video details. When we play a video in youtube and if we do right click, then we can see an option *called copy debug info*. If we copy that then there are lot of fields comes as below, I am just curious to know the details of these below fields.

```
{
  "ns": "yt",
  "el": "detailpage",
  "cpn": "TA1LSqRVROm9Q2rb",
  "docid": "tPDj7FhbUso",
  "ver": 2,
  "referrer": "https://www.youtube.com/feed/history",
  "cmt": "208.944",
  "ei": "Ups5X-iDO8ng4-EP7o6KwAg",
  "fmt": "247",
  "fs": "0",
  "rt": "151.471",
  "of": "yuFWq23SkzutVGx461bO4g",
  "euri": "",
  "lact": 7,
  "cl": "326301777",
  "mos": 0,
  "state": "4",
  "vm": "CAEQARgEKiBsUmpoTXRxc1czUTVHZ2RJbmktOXBNdnY3X3JnV3ItNjoyQUdiNlo4T3BuV0tmTXhwbW5wWDZjUDA3X3JPYU5PXzVSd1Bha2szZE9jNEhCY0ZQTkE",
  "volume": 100,
  "subscribed": "1",
  "cbr": "Chrome",
  "cbrver": "84.0.4147.125",
  "c": "WEB",
  "cver": "2.20200814.00.00",
  "cplayer": "UNIPLAYER",
  "cos": "Macintosh",
  "cosver": "10_15_6",
  "hl": "en_US",
  "cr": "IN",
  "len": "268.121",
  "fexp": "23744176,23804281,23839597,23856950,23857950,23858057,23859802,23862346,23868323,23880389,23882502,23883098,23884386,23890960,23895671,23900945,23907595,23911055,23915993,23916148,23918272,23918598,23927906,23928508,23930220,23931938,23934047,23934090,23934970,23936412,24631210,3300107,3300133,3300161,3313321,3316358,3316377,3317374,3317643,3318816,3318887,3318889,3319024,9405957,9449243",
  "afmt": "251",
  "inview": "NaN",
  "vct": "208.944",
  "vd": "268.121",
  "vpl": "207.000-208.944",
  "vbu": "204.000-268.121",
  "vpa": "1",
  "vsk": "0",
  "ven": "0",
  "vpr": "1",
  "vrs": "4",
  "vns": "2",
  "vec": "null",
  "vemsg": "",
  "vvol": "1",
  "vdom": "1",
  "vsrc": "1",
  "vw": 1159,
  "vh": 652,
  "creationTime": 158827.80500000808,
  "totalVideoFrames": 128,
  "droppedVideoFrames": 0,
  "corruptedVideoFrames": 0,
  "lct": "208.944",
  "lsk": false,
  "lmf": false,
  "lbw": "993748.652",
  "lhd": "0.057",
  "lst": "0.000",
  "laa": "itag=251,type=3,seg=26,range=3299085-3408885,time=260.0-268.1,off=0,len=109801,end=1,eos=1",
  "lva": "itag=247,type=3,seg=53,range=17411843-17472031,time=264.0-268.1,off=0,len=60189,end=1,eos=1",
  "lar": "itag=251,type=3,seg=26,range=3299085-3408885,time=260.0-268.1,off=0,len=109801,end=1,eos=1",
  "lvr": "itag=247,type=3,seg=53,range=17411843-17472031,time=264.0-268.1,off=0,len=60189,end=1,eos=1",
  "lab": "200.001-268.121",
  "lvb": "204.000-268.080",
  "ismb": 3000000,
  "relative_loudness": "-5.140",
  "optimal_format": "720p",
  "user_qual": "auto",
  "debug_videoId": "tPDj7FhbUso",
  "0sz": false,
  "op": "",
  "yof": false,
  "dis": "",
  "gpu": "Intel(R)_UHD_Graphics_630",
  "cgr": true,
  "debug_playbackQuality": "hd720",
  "debug_date": "Mon Aug 17 2020 02:19:46 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
}
```

For an example - docid filed is known for the video Id of youtube. Like that I wanna know other field details. If anyone can help me with, that would be great..

Comment: Is this the YouTube api you are talking about, if so please add your code if not please fix your tags.  If this is regarding the YouTube web application you should probably be posting this on https://webapps.stackexchange.com/ as its not really programming related.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there is a easy way to do this - *(AFAIK, no YouTube Data API exposes such values)*, but, if you really want to check, you can enter to `view-source:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<VIDEO_ID>` - where `<VIDEO_ID>` is the id of the YouTube video.

There are some values obtained from the `copy debug info` - but not all of them, I'm affraid.